# How to execute a python script from a servlet?

Tags: java, python, servlets

I have written the following code for the servlet:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Summarize extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        String str = req.getParameter("txt");

        try {
        //instead of writing just test.py, write the whole path to the python script it will work perfectly
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python test.py");
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    p.getInputStream()));
            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = null;
            System.out.println(p.toString());
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                buf.append(line);
            }
            System.out.println(buf.length());
            out.println("this is summarize class");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This code won't return anything but If I write the same code in a simple java class the code works perfectly fine.

I have also checked the python script, it's running perfectly fine.
Is there any way to fix this?

**Update:

The following code will now work just read the comment just after the try statement**

Answer (score 2):

I recommend works with [Jython](http://www.jython.org/)

> Jython is an implementation of the Python programming language in Java, running on the Java Virtual Machine (JVM), as opposed to the standard implementation of Python which is implemented in C (CPython). Python developers can use it to take advantage of the vast libraries available to the Java community, which means adding a bit of Java integration in the application.

An example [here](https://blog.smartbear.com/programming/embedding-jython-in-java-applications/)

```
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;
import org.python.core.*;

public class SimpleExample {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws PyException
   {
       PythonInterpreter pi = new PythonInterpreter();
       pi.set("integer", new PyInteger(42));
       pi.exec("square = integer*integer");
       PyInteger square = (PyInteger)pi.get("square");
       System.out.println(“square: ” + square.asInt());
   }
}
```

*source* [Embedding Jython in Java Applications](https://blog.smartbear.com/programming/embedding-jython-in-java-applications/)

Comment: I have to execute in servlet doPost() method, not in a simple class which has the main method

Comment: You can use the jython interpreter or command executor into your servlet.

Comment: i just want to run a python script from my servlet and primt the output, can u provide a code for that?